# Where does the xmlHttprequest takes place here?

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have a small doubt regarding data communication in ajax.I have read that json is used to interchange data whereas xmlhttp is also used to interchange data.
My question is

> If both json and xmlhttrequest combines to communicate asynchronously in ajax?
>   or
>   Any one of the above is used independently to Communicate?

My working code to autocomplete textbox using ajax is

```
<script type="text/javascript">
           $(document).ready(function () {
           $("#txtProjectName").autocomplete({
                  source: function (request, response) {
                      $.ajax({
                          type: "POST",
                          contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                          url: "service.asmx/getinfo",
                          data: "{'prefixText':'" + $("#txtProjectName").val() + "'}",
                          dataType: "json",
                          success: function (data) {
                              response(data.d);
                          },
                          error: function (result) {
                              alert("Error");
                          }
```

If possible,pls explain me with related to given code or just explain me clearly without given code.

THANKS IN ADVANCE!!!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not sure whether I understand what you are asking, but I'll try to explain.

AJAX stands for *Asynchronous JavaScript and XML* and by default has nothing in common with JSON which is *JavaScript Object Notation*. The important thing to know is that it uses *XMLHttpRequest* object to send HTTP requests to the server and in communication it can use both XML and JSON(despite having XML in its name).

You have to distinguish what is used to communicate(XHR) from what is used as data format(JSON, XML, HTML, plain text).

You can read about XHR [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest/Using_XMLHttpRequest).